80's early 90's show like The OC, orphan or run-away boy selling dinosaur eggs?
I remember waiting to watch the next episode of a pretty sad show when I was a kid, I'm guessing around 1985-1990, but I didn't get to see it - I think the A-Team was on instead that day, so maybe I had gotten the times mixed up. I'm remeinded of it every now and then, and it makes me a bit melancholy for some reason.
I think the main character was a poor white kid, and he might have had a sister. In the episode I saw, he was trying to make money selling a round rock on the side of the road as a "dinosaur egg". It was based in the USA I think. 
It reminds me of an early 80's version of The OC.... poor kid in suburban wealthy school/community, I think being bullied by the other kids. Maybe he was adopted.
Anyhow, it would be great if I can finally get this cleared up... I'm 37 now!!

It turns out that it was a movie, Help Wanted: Kids, that was part of a Disney Movie Series......... no wonder I never got to see the second episode. I can now move on with my life at last. It also isn't as sad as I had remembered, suppose I just felt sorry for the little boy and girl trying to sell things on the side of the road - I was young and still a nice little boy back then:-(

The Disney Sunday Movie (1986-1988) initially aired as ABC's lead-off
  program on Sundays, running from 7:00 to 9:00 p.m. Eastern Time.[17]
  By this point, the format was similar to a movie-of-the-week. Gary
  Barton, a Disney senior vice president, was in charge of the program.
  "Help Wanted: Kids" was the first episode's film.

